# sitecore back/forward button disabled, history points?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm using sitecore 6.5 content editor and it the back and forward buttons are disabled in 6.5.  I've decompiled the code and it looks like it could be related to history points?

I recently upgraded from 6.2, perhaps I am missing something in the web.config or sitecore.config, but a simple comparison using beyond compare doesn't really lead me anywhere.

Any suggestions would be awesome.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the UI? How does it look?

Comment: added a screen shot, highlighted the problem buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI this was a confirmed bug that was resolved in version 7, not sure if there is a patch for previous versions though.